# Share files between projects in visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a F# project which is compiled for .Net 4.5. However, I need it to be compiled .Net 4.0 too. I created another project target .Net 4.0 and I can copy all the same files from the .Net 4.5 project to the newly created project.

The project referred some NuGet libraries which have different packages for .Net 4.5 and 4.0 so I cannot simply change the project's .Net version and recompile.  How to avoid maintain two copies of the same files? I know VS 2015 has shared files function.

Answer (score 0):

try "Add As Link".

`Project` menu > `Add Existing Item...` and in the `Add` drop-down list, click `Add As Link`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using source control to share files.

The source control has one copy.

Having a multiple copies on your hard drive is actually a good thing.  One project can use a stable version while another project updates and tests a new version.

The only disadvantage is if one project checks in changes, you must remember to do a 'get' for the other projects.